# what is the most reliable method to get a file from remote server in php

Tags: php, file

I am writing a PHP script that will be installed on a users server.  I want to pull a file from MY remote server (a zip file) and write it to the local server that the script is running on.

I can do it just fine use file_get_contents and also using Snoopy.

However, the issue is that my script will be distributed to lots of people who will have a variety of servers.  They will range from freebie webspace to their own dedicated rack with everything in between :)  I can't be certain that the correct options will be enabled for file_get_contents to work and I know that, if certain options are disabled, it will be unlikely that the user will be able to get them enabled.

So,  I am thinking that, pretty much, the only thing I can guarantee is the they will have PHP 4 + what is the best way to pull the remote file - IE: Which way has the best chance of working on such a large range of webservers :

1. file_get_contents
2. Snoopy (using fetch)
3. fsockopen

Any ideas or comments would be MUCH appreciated :)

Comment: What about the curl implementation in PHP?

Comment: Send a courier with a thumb drive. Most reliable, but not quite as fast as one would like.

Comment: Matt : LOL Like it!   Phill Cross & madflow - I thought of CURL but can't be sure that it will be enabled - Some of these servers are going to be free hosting space - Some will be low end (IE: $5 per month HostGator "unlimited" type hosting) - Some will be top end stuff with configurable options - Thing is, I need to try and cover the lowest common denominator where possible.

Comment: If it was me designing the transfer system, I'd personally find as many ways to transfer the files across and order them by ease of use / efficiency. I'd then attempt to perform them in that order. If the first one (for example cUrl) fails, move onto the next process (ie FTP / etc).

Comment: I was kinda thinking the same thing to be honest - And the last resort would, of course, be FTP.  What I would like to know though is what the most likely order of failure is - IE: What would be the mos probable order to attempt things?